# How to redirect all existing .php files with exceptions in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

My current .htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . redirect1.php [L]
```

With this setting, users can still access the original `.php` files without going through `redirect1.php` which is undesirable. So I would like to send all requests for existing `.php` and `.html` files to a separate file, lets say `redirect2.php` which would check if the user is an admin.

However, this would restrict the users from sending ajax requests to any php file, so there should be an exception for those. Maybe if the file is called `file.script.php` it should also be ignored.

To summarize:

```
Existing .php & .html     ->  redirect2.php
Existing .script.php      ->  NO REDIRECT
Any other existing file   ->  NO REDIRECT
Non existing file         ->  redirect1.php
```

Comment: Just a tip which might save some confusion in future: "redirect" normally refers to _telling the browser to re-request a different page_. The rules you show here are _rewrites_, telling the _server_ to render a different page from what was requested. `RewriteRule` directives can perform both tasks (a rule with the `[R]` flag is a redirect, otherwise it's an internal rewrite).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it this way:

```sh
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# ignore .script.php file
RewriteRule \.script\.php$ - [L,NC]

# handle existing php and html files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule \.(?:php|html?)$ redirect2.php [L,NC]

# handle non-existing files and directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . redirect1.php [L]
```

Comment: Note that you don't need to allow direct access to `redirect1.php` and `redirect2.php` for the proposed scheme to work. The first rule could just be `RewriteRule ^.+\.script\.php$ - [L,NC]`

Comment: It is just for safety. It is not needed in current set of rules but moment someone adds a `/` in target like `RewriteRule \.(?:php|html?)$ /redirect2.php [L,NC]` it will cause a rewrite loop.

Comment: Why would adding a slash cause a loop? Also, if it does, it's better to resolve that then (you'll soon spot it when you test the rule change) than to weaken security by allowing the user to directly request scripts which should be internal only.

Comment: `Why would adding a slash cause a loop?`: Please try it out with rewrite log enabled and you will see 500 error with `LimitInternalRecursion`

Comment: You can reproduce it easily by putting a `/` in target as I suggested. Not every behavior of `mod_rewrite` is documented. I have learnt about this only by debugging. `mod_rewrite` stops rewriting when `source URI == target URI`. In `.htaccess` leading `/` is always stripped from source path to make it e.g. `file.php` and when we have `/file.php` in target source will never be same as target resulting in  `LimitInternalRecursion`. It won't happen in `<VirtualHost>` because it is not run in per-directory context like .htaccess where leading `/` is not stripped from source.

Comment: Tha's not what I suggested above. I suggested to use `RewriteRule \.(?:php|html?)$ /redirect2.php [L,NC]` in 2nd rule. With that in place just request `http://localhost/redirect2.php` and then see the behavior.

Comment: You're right, it's specific to `.htaccess` files, and I slightly messed up my attempt to reproduce there. My apologies. Arguably, the best solution is to not use `.htaccess` files, but I realise a lot of people are on shared hosts and don't have access to the real configuration files.

Comment: It looks like using [the `[END]` flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_end) instead of `[L]` solves that case nicely, although there might be downsides to it that I haven't thought of.